# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't detect my bc vault device

Tags: usb

First I have to let you know I am new in Ubuntu and I am just a user. (tired of window OS)

I have Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop computer . I bought BC Vault device, and the company has driver for Linux O.S. I downloaded the driver and installed it.  After opening the software, it does not see the device.

The company offered these to solutions:

```
1- Description: Linux may not recognize the device due to a permissions issue with the USB HID device. Due to large number of different Linux distributions you might need to adopt the following script/info to yours.

RedHat: Using USBGUARD

For Debian like distributions:

#-------------------------------------------------
# allow USB access (depends on linux distro)
# for Debian based you could try something like

echo "KERNEL==\"hidraw*\", SUBSYSTEM==\"hidraw\", ATTRS{manufacturer}==\"Real Security\", TAG+=\"uaccess\"" | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/70-becoz-premission.rules > /dev/null

# apply changes with:

sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger

2-For Mint:

echo "KERNEL==\"hidraw*\", SUBSYSTEMS==\"usb\", ATTRS{manufacturer}==\"Real Security\", TAG+=\"uaccess\"" | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/70-becoz-premission.rule/dev/null
```

I don’t know much about  coding and I don't know if I have to make some changes to these codes or... I want to make sure if these are the right solutions.
Please help . Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know what a BC vault is, online searches tell me it's a bitcoin wallet but it's probably best if you clarify.  From what you found, you didn't provide any clues as to when the documentation was written, what releases or really software stack ages the instructions were written for, which is needed to be known to know if changes need to be made for your 2018-April (18.04) release of Ubuntu.